# ApacheSolr integration

Tags: 7, search

I have a Drupal multisite website, with Apache Solr Search Integration, which is up and running very well in the live server. I am trying to replicate the same website, on another server to use it as a development environment. I have copied all the code and replicated the DB and changed the settings.php file accordingly, but I am getting the following errors.

- Memeber profile is not completed.
- Apache solr is not integrated on to the server.

Can anyone help me with the steps which I have to follow during the process?

Answer (score 1):

Solr is a server and you must set up the parameters to this server correctly in your site at this address: `admin/settings/apachesolr/settings`.

Is there any errors in the status report ?

Answer (score 1):

When cloning your live site, you inherited the Solr settings from its database. It's likely that the Solr server for live site is either running on the same server or on some host un-reachable from the development environment.

You need to setup a Solr server for your development environment and configure your development site to use this server. You can use the same server to host your live and development Solr, but you need to use [different indexes](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes) for each site.